# Do I have to buy ARR if i have original Final Fantasy XIV disc without account?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I do not have a Final Fantasy XIV account but I have Final Fantasy XIV original disc. Do I have to buy A Realm Reborn to play it?

Answer (score 1):

**Generally speaking, no, you will not have to buy version 2.0 if you have the 1.0 disk.**

According to [my research](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/678051-final-fantasy-xiv-online-a-realm-reborn/65588452):

> No. If you have the game installed, you’ll have to download a new client and install ARR through there. If you don’t have it installed, you can still activate ARR using the serial from the original game. Buddy passes from the collector’s edition will still work for ARR. And we all get a free month…whether it’s your first time logging in or if you are a returning player

On PC, owners of the original can download the client [here](http://sqex.to/ffxiv_client_en).

The important point is that you will use your serial to activate the client and it shouldn't matter if you didn't have an FFIV account. Also, if your copy was a CE, you are eligible for all the ARR CE content as well.

Note that you are limited to the systems that you originally purchased the game for so if you want to play across systems, you will need to have purchased a version for each system at some point, meaning that if you have the PC version and want to play the PS3 version, you will need to have purchased a copy of the PS3 version previously or will have to purchase a new one.